# write() does not write sequentialy?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have found that `write()` method of `stream.Writable` class does not write data sequentially. When I an sending am attachment to the server in chunks, this code assembles data chunks in wrong order if no delay occurs. If I put a debug message like console.log() in the middle of the loop (like to dump the data to watch what is being written, actually), this bug disappears. So, what is the race condition in this code ? Looks like I am enforcing a sequential assembling of the file, so I do not understand what is wrong.

My code:

```
function join_chunks(company_id,attachment_id,num_chunks) {
    var stream;
    var file;
    var output_filename=ATTACHMENTS_PATH + '/comp' + company_id + '/' + attachment_id + '.data';
    var input_filename;
    var chunk_data;
    var chunk_count=0;
    stream=fs.createWriteStream(output_filename,{flags:'w+',mode: 0666});
    console.log('joining files:');
    for(var i=0;i<num_chunks;i++) {
        input_filename=ATTACHMENTS_PATH + '/comp' + company_id + '/' + attachment_id + '-' + (i+1) + '.chunk';
        console.log(input_filename);
        fs.readFile(input_filename , (err, chunk_data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            stream.write(chunk_data,function() {
                chunk_count++;
                if (chunk_count==num_chunks) {
                    console.log('join finished. closing stream');
                    stream.end();
                }
            });
        });
    }   
}
```

The console:

```
joining files:
/home/attachments/comp-2084830518/67-1.chunk
/home/attachments/comp-2084830518/67-2.chunk
/home/attachments/comp-2084830518/67-3.chunk
/home/attachments/comp-2084830518/67-4.chunk
join finished. closing stream
```

Node version: v6.9.2

Comment: `fs.readFile` is asynchronous; you immediately queue `num_chunks` file operations, but they won't necessarily complete in the order you queued them. You'll likely have to wait until they all complete, then put them in order and write them.

Comment: @qxz, good eye. the reading was the problem and not the writing. I replaced the reading with sequential flow and everything runs fine. If you answer the question I will accept it. The other answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`stream.write` is an asynchronous operation. This means that multiple calls to it may be serviced out of order.

If you want your writes to happen in order, use `stream.writeSync`, or use the callback argument to `stream.write` to sequence your writes.

Comment: Thanks. Is there somewhere in the documentation saying that Writable.write() method executes out of order ? Or where did you read that ?

Comment: As I understand it, `Writable` stream has been created for the purpose of sequential writing so, it should be keeping the order by default, in FIFO mode.

Comment: @Nulik Generally speaking, all system calls in Node are asynchronous unless the documentation explicitly says otherwise. Outside of explicit synchronization points like callbacks, there are no guarantees about the ordering of async calls.

Comment: asynchronousity is not the same concept as order. You may write pieces of data asynchronously but keep them order. That's why I want a clear reference to the docs, and not an assumption.

Comment: @Nulik Asynchronous callbacks can be invoked at any time, which means that they can complete at any time. The order is not guaranteed.